# How to reference text boxes that have been added in run time

Tags: vb.net, textbox

My program creates a random number of TextBox controls when the form loads. I need to then reference what has been typed into these textboxes elsewhere in the code. My problem is is that an error comes up when I try to do so. Below is my code.

```
Dim userAct As New TextBox
userAct.Location = New Point(386, 379)
userAct.Size = New Size(95, 34)
userAct.Font = New Font("Luicida Fax", 12.0!)
userAct.BackColor = SystemColors.InactiveCaption
userAct.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
userAct.Multiline = True
Me.Controls.Add(userAct)
```

`userAct` is created but I cannot reference this textbox anywhere within the code. Is there anyway to overcome this? Thanks

Comment: You could set the `Name` of each one and reference them via the `Controls` collection of the form by that name. Alternatively, assign an array or `List` to a field and populate it with your `TextBoxes`, then access them by index.

Comment: is it because you don't see the events on the list when  you type your code ea: TextBox1_TextChanged? Your textbox object should be at the top of your class so it stay global to your class and lets you use the object in any sub or function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're declaring `userAct` in a sub/function procedure. Although the control is added to the form at runtime, the variable `userAct` goes out of scope after the sub/function is completed. There are several possible solutions to this, but would suggest the following

You can use the code you have, but also assign a "userAct" string to the .Name property and access the control using something like

```
directcast(Me.Controls.Find("userAct", False)(0),TextBox)
```

This can then be used in exactly the same way as a normal TextBox ..

```
directcast(Me.Controls.Find("userAct", False)(0),TextBox).Text="Hi there"
```

or

```
Dim S as string = directcast(Me.Controls.Find("userAct", False)(0),TextBox)(0).Text
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this to get a control by its name

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function ControlByName(Of T As Control)(ByVal parent As Control, ByVal name As String) As T
    For Each c As T In parent.ChildControls(Of T)()
        If c.Name = name Then
            Return c
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Use this method to get all the controls on the form, even within containers

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function ChildControls(Of T As Control)(ByVal parent As Control) As List(Of T)
    Dim result As New List(Of T)
    For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is T Then result.Add(CType(ctrl, T))
        result.AddRange(ctrl.ChildControls(Of T)())
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

(Control.Controls only returns controls contained immediately in Control)

In your case, this would be used like so

```
Dim userAct As New TextBox
userAct.Location = New Point(386, 379)
userAct.Size = New Size(95, 34)
userAct.Font = New Font("Luicida Fax", 12.0!)
userAct.BackColor = SystemColors.InactiveCaption
userAct.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
userAct.Multiline = True
userAct.Name = "userActName" ' new
Me.Controls.Add(userAct)

Dim myUserAct As TextBox = Me.ControlByName(Of TextBox)("userActName")
```

Alternatively, you can use this non-generic version

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function ControlByName(ByVal parent As Control, ByVal name As String) As Control
    For Each c As Control In parent.ChildControls
        If c.Name = name Then
            Return c
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function

<Extension()> _
Public Function ChildControls(ByVal parent As Control) As List(Of Control)
    Return ChildControls(Of Control)(parent)
End Function
```

but you would need to cast

```
Dim myUserAct As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.ControlByName("userActName"), TextBox)
```